# SQL Error: 1364 - Field 'description' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, sql, mybb

I am getting this error when attempting to insert into `mybb`'s `mybb_settinggroups` SQL table:

> SQL Error: 1364 - Field 'description' doesn't have a default value
>   Query: INSERT INTO mybb_settinggroups (name,title,disporder,isdefault)
>   VALUES ('lock','Lock Settings',1,0)

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `description` would seem to be declared `NOT NULL` with no default value.  So, you need to include it in the `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO mybb_settinggroups (name, title, disporder, isdefault, description)
    VALUES ('lock', 'Lock Settings', 1, 0, 'no description available');
```

You may have a more reasonable description in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can either drop not null constraint or alter the table on description column 
as below

```
        alter table name alter column 
         description 
         set 
         default 'no description'
```

Comment: While normally this would be an OK solution, I wouldn't recommend modifying `mybb`'s default schema, as it could lead to problems and inconsistencies in functionality in the `mybb` application itself.

Comment: As there are cases where data needs to be inserted without manually entering it likewise I have posted the above query